# Google Sheets: Math Problem for Investment Strategy

Tags: google-sheets

In a test investment strategy, I'm looking at using a Margin Loan, and increasing the Loan each year to buy additional shares such that the Loan/Value Ratio remains the same:

[image]

I haven't been able to re-arrange a formula to solve for the value of "Additional Stock" in Row 7 - the values I added in the img were manually included by trial and error.

The "formula" is expressed as:

`LVR = (Previous Loan + Additional Stock) / (Stock Value Including Growth + Additional Stock)`

For example, in Year 1, it becomes:

`25% = ($2,500 + X) / ($11,200 + X)`

Can anyone suggest a way to solve this formula for "X"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=($B13*C3-B11)/(1-$B13)
```

Comment: Spot on!  I'd finally got past my mental block, and was just about to post the exact same answer.  Thank you. :)